# Write repeated expressions within a rule more simply

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule, argument-patterns, coding-style

Is it possible to shorten the length of a (delayed) rule (i.e. `lhs :> rhs`) when there are expressions which repeat several times? Those expressions involve values of the patterns matched in `lhs`, so ideas that come to my mind, such as creating a pure function that takes the repeated elements as arguments, do not work.

A simple example of what I refer to can be:

```
Replace[ list , a_ :> {IntegerDigits[a],Length@IntegerDigits[a],IntegerDigits[a][[1]]} ]
```

Is there a way to write in such case `IntegerDigits[a]` only once instead of three in there?

Comment: `With[{rd = RealDigits[a]}, {a, Length@a, First@a}]`

Comment: `Through[{Identity, Length, First}[RealDigits[a]]]`

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want though? `Length@RealDigits[anything]` will always be $2$, because [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html) always returns a list of two elements. Was that supposed to be `Length@First@RealDigits[a]` instead?

Comment: I've edited it and changed the function for `IntegerDigits`. The function doesn't directly relate to my problem, it was just a simple example to clarify a bit what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the thing you want to use repeatedly using a variable (instead of a pure function):

```
Replace[list, a_ :> {b = IntegerDigits[a], Length@b, b[[1]]}]
```